# Random Image generator app does not want to work on android studio 3.1.4

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So for a small assignment, I was tasked with making a program that will generate a random image from a file on the computer

what I did was move the icons from the desktop to the drawable folder

[in the image you can see that the files are there under the drawable folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvL0B.png)

[Here is the user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhaDE.png)

the code is also available in the picture. The issue is that the program would crash after I press the button and no picture is ever shown.
It looks perfect to me and at this point, I do not know what is wrong with it

Thank you for whoever answers this

Ps. I am using a mac for this (not sure how important this piece of info is )

Comment: Where does the Logcat say the error is happening at? Also it would probably be very helpful to include code here on post (everybody might not want to look at the picture^)

Comment: will do, it is my first post so i didn't know i should do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image.setImageResource(i)` you are passing random number in the setImageResources

> You are passing wrong Image Resource Id

so replace with the `image.setImageResource(array[i])` because your image resources ids stored in this array

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `image.setImageResource(i)` by `image.setImageResource(array[i])`.

What you want is to access the resource id which is stored in the array.